# Dollar sign in function __text__signature__

Tags: python, arguments, signature

**Input**

```
def f(no, matter='what', *iz, **here):
    pass

f.__call__.__text_signature__
```

**Output**

```
'($self, /, *args, **kwargs)'
```

What is the `$` in the signature talking about?
(I'm not obsessed with the `self` thing, rather a bit confused about the dollar sign appearing there)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$` is an explicit marker for `self` and similar arguments, present to make `inspect.Signature`'s detection of such arguments a little more robust. See [Larry Hastings's message](https://bugs.python.org/msg209301) from back when he introduced this use of `$`, and [the code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.10.0/Lib/inspect.py#L2104) in `inspect.py` that processes the `$`.

Comment: Thank you! I was being tempted to imagine that `$` is something related to the `template` module!